# How do I pass multiple values in a single parameter for a stored proc using TVP?

Tags: sql-server

I want to pass multiple brand names in the same parameter. I'm trying to employ this using TVP but have some issues regarding it.

Here's the sample code:

```
CREATE TYPE BRAND AS TABLE
(
    BRANDName NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
)

create proc SALES @Brandparameter BRAND READONLY AS

create table #sales(Categories,Volume)
insert into #sales(Categories,Volume)
select categories,sum(case when Brand=@Brandparameter then [volume] end)
from sales_table
group by categories

exec SALES @BRANDNAMES

DECLARE @BRANDNAMES AS BRAND
INSERT INTO @BRANDNAMES 
VALUES('Brand1'),('Brand2')
```

When I execute the procedure it gives the following error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@BRANDNAMES"

This the sales_table

```
_______________________________
| Categories | Brand | volume |
|-----------------------------|
| Category 1 | Brand1| 1000   |
| .......    | ..... | .....  |
|_____________________________|
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `@Brandparameter` is a table type, you have to use it in the same way you would use a table (i.e. SELECT from it), so you would need something like:

```
SELECT Categories, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Brand IN (SELECT BRANDName FROM @Brandparameter) THEN [Volume] END)
FROM   sales_table
GROUP BY Categories;
```